# Is there a way to use two if conditions in list comprehensions in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I had a list

```
my_list = ['91 9925479326','18002561245','All the best','good']
```

Now I want to ignore the strings in the list starting with `91` and `18`  like below

```
result = []
for i in my_list:
   if not '91' in i:
      if not '18' in i:
         result.append(i)
```

So here I want to achieve this with list comprehensions.

Is there anyway to write two if conditions in list compreshensions?

Comment: @jamylak: I had taken that as an example anyway thanks for editing.

Comment: Beware that your tests just check if `91` and `18` are present in _any_ position of the string. You should use `str.startswith` instead: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
[i for i in my_list if '91' not in i and '18' not in i]
```

Note you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in function.

Comment: (+1) for a correct answer and for changing `not '91' in i` to `'91' not in i`.

Comment: This answer becomes not so concise and clean as soon as you have five of ten instead of two values to check.

Comment: Can we do the same with startwith function because sometimes the list consists of the strings starting with 91 and some times starting with 18, what ever it may be the strings starting with 91 or 18 should be ignored from the list.actually the strings here are phone numbers 91 9885564213 and 1800 3236 2365

Comment: Also I must note that this solution is incorrect at all, you must check values with `startswith` not with `in`

Comment: @IgorChubin -- this answer does what the OP requested -- mainly translated the given for loop into a list-comp.

Comment: @mgilson: `Now i want to ignore the strings in the list starting with 91 and 18 like below`

Answer (score 12):

If you have more than two values (91 and 18)
or they are dynamically produced
it is better to use this construction:

```
[i for i in my_list if not i.startswith(('91', '18'))]
```

Or if you want to check if `91` and `18` are in the strings (not only in the beginning), use `in` instead of `startswith`:

```
[i for i in my_list if all(x not in i for x in ['91', '18'])]
```

Example of usage:

```
>>> my_list = ['91 9925479326','18002561245','All the best','good']
>>> [i for i in my_list if all(not i.startswith(x) for x in ['91', '18'])]
['All the best', 'good']
>>>
```

Comment: I prefer: `[i for i in my_list if not any(i.startswith(x) for x in ['91', '18'])]` but I guess it's personal preference

Comment: `.startswith` also accepts a tuple of strings, so it can be shortened to `[i for i in my_list if not i.startswith(('91', '18'))]`.

Comment: @MRAB: Thank you for the perfect hint! I updated the answer and added your variant to it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can "merge" both conditions:

```
if ((not '91' in i) and (not '18' in i))
```

Comment: Or simplify using [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `if not ('91' in i or '18' in i)